# D3 tree node collapse

Tags: angular, d3.js, electron

I'm struggling to implement the node collapse feature with D3. I got to a point where I can collapse and expand a node but the transformation is not smooth and the parent nodes of the collapsed node are destroyed.

```
  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
    this.htmlElement = this.element.nativeElement;
    this.host = D3.select(this.element.nativeElement);
  }

  draw(issue) {
    if (!issue) {
      return;
    }

    var zoom = D3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1, 10])
      .on("zoom", zoomed);

    var nodes = D3.hierarchy(issue, function (d) {
      return d.children;
    });

    nodes = this.treemap(nodes);
    while (this.htmlElement.hasChildNodes()) {
      this.htmlElement.removeChild(this.htmlElement.lastChild);
    }
    var svg = this.host.append('svg')
      .attr("width", this.width + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
      .attr("height", this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom);
    var g = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")");
    svg.call(zoom);

    var link = g.selectAll(".link")
      .data(nodes.descendants().slice(1))
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function (d) {
        return "M" + d.y + "," + d.x
          + "C" + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2 + "," + d.x
          + " " + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2 + "," + d.parent.x
          + " " + d.parent.y + "," + d.parent.x;
      });

    var node = g.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes.descendants())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function (d) {
        return "node" +
          (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf");
      })
      .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
      })
      .on('click', (function (d) {
        if (d.data.children) {
          d.data._children = d.data.children;
          d.data.children = null;
        } else {
          d.data.children = d.data._children;
          d.data._children = null;
        }
        this.draw(d.data);
      }).bind(this));

    node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 10);

  node.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
     });

  node.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    })
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + issue.y + "," + issue.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

    nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);


    // adds the text to the node
    node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("x", function (d) { return d.children ? -13 : 13; })
      .style("text-anchor", function (d) {
        return d.children ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .text(function (d) { return d.data.name; });

    function zoomed() {
      g.attr("transform", D3.event.transform);
    }
  }
```

Would appreciate some help with getting it to work :)
I'm trying to implement based on this post: https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd

Edit I: I have also added the code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f3suie

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz with code?

Comment: Hey again Safiyya :)
I'm not sure what stackblitz is. Checking it out.

Comment: I have added the code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f3suie) @Safiyya